# SSL error when starting from crontab but not when starting manually -- what is going wrong?

Tags: python, unix, cron, aiohttp

I have a little telegram bot running on a raspberry pi. It uses the `aiogram` framework which makes use of `asyncio` and `aiohttp`. When starting the bot via `python bot.py`, everything works well. But if I add `@reboot <path to python> <path to bot.py> > bot.py.log` to my pi's crontab, the log gives the following error:

```
Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('2001:67c:4e8:f004::9', 443, 0, 0)]
```

I don't understand why this error only occurs when starting via crontab and never when starting manually. I pasted the precise command I am using for crontab in the pi's console and don't get the error. Any ideas of what happened and how to fix this?

**EDIT:**
Since I come to believe more and more that this could be a problem with python and `aiohttp`, here is the complete error stack:

```
File "/home/pi/bot_directory/TelegramBot.py", line 467, in <module>
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)

File "/home/pi/miniforge3/envs/bot_directory/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 41, in start_polling
    executor.start_polling(reset_webhook=reset_webhook, timeout=timeout, relax=relax, fast=fast)

File "/home/pi/miniforge3/envs/bot_directory/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 309, in start_polling
    loop.run_until_complete(self._startup_polling())

File "/home/pi/miniforge3/envs/bot_directory/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()

File "/home/pi/miniforge3/envs/bot_directory/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 360, in _startup_polling
    await self._welcome()

File "/home/pi/miniforge3/envs/bot_directory/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 350, in _welcome
    user = await self.dispatcher.bot.me

File "/home/pi/miniforge3/envs/bot_directory/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 29, in me
    setattr(self, '_me', await self.get_me())

File "/home/pi/miniforge3/envs/bot_directory/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 217, in get_me
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_ME, payload)

File "/home/pi/miniforge3/envs/bot_directory/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/base.py", line 208, in request
    return await api.make_request(self.session, self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,

File "/home/pi/miniforge3/envs/bot_directory/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 142, in make_request
    raise exceptions.NetworkError(f"aiohttp client throws an error: {e.__class__.__name__}: {e}")

Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Temporary failure in name resolution]
```

Comment: All crontab problems are environment problems. Make your program run under `env -i /path/to/program`. If it does that successfully, it is ready for cron.

Comment: @Jens together with the `env -i` my program starts and performs well. In my crontab there is a `cd /path/to/program/directory` before the actual execution of the command that starts the program and this doesn't wirk with `env -i`. In fact, `env -i cd some/directory` always fails. Anyway, further ideas on what the issue could be?

Comment: @Jens If I add `@reboot cd /path/to/programm/directory && ls > ls_test.log` to my crontab, thinks work well. So I assume that my program is startet in the right directory. So I'm still confused why the results when starting manually and via crontab differ.

Comment: `env -i cd ...` works fine here. When you say "fails", this is not specific. What is the error message? Why do you think it fails? What is the actual crontab line?

Comment: @Jens The error message for `env -i cd folder` is `"cd": no such file or directory` and this  happens with all directories, even those that should clearly be there because they get displayed by `env -i ls`. Thus, no idea what goes wrong here. I tried several versions of the crontab command, all result in the same error. For example `@reboot cd /path/to/program && /path/to/python/binary program.py > program.py.log 2>program.py.error`.

Comment: Well, `cd` is a shell built-in and on your system it is apaprently not a stand-alone executable. When you test with `env -i /path/to/program` you must put the `cd` into the program.

Comment: I also tried to put the commands into a .sh, started it with crontab and again it starts the bot and produces the above mentioned error which doesn’t occur when starting manually.

Comment: Which user's crontab runs the program? Is it the same user as when you run it from the command line? To spot any differences, place a `set` command in the .sh to see all env. variables.